# compiling error "assignment from incompatible pointer type"

Tags: pointers, gcc

I get this error:

```
$ gcc -Wall -g translate.c support.c scanner.c -o translate
support.c: In function ‘readTokens’:
support.c:66:18: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     a[count] = token;
              ^
```

here is the readTokens():

```
void
readTokens(char *fileName, char** a[])
{
FILE *fp;
char *token;
int count = 0;

fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
if (fp == 0)
    {
    fprintf(stderr,"file %s could not be opened for reading\n", fileName);
    exit(1);
    }

token = readLine(fp);
while(!feof(fp))
    {
    a[count] = token;
    ++count;
    free(token);
    token = readLine(fp);
    }

fclose(fp);
}
```

I asked a question similar to this earlier and thought I could figure it out from responses but it is still giving me trouble.

Comment: Type of 'token' is 'char *', type of 'a[]' is 'char **', so types of them incompatible.  My guess is  type of a[] may be 'char *'.

Comment: its not a[] is an array of strings created in the function before that and im trying to read the tokens and pass them into the array through the while function

Comment: it works if i write a[count] = (char**)token; but when i read the array out to the screen to check it its just the final item in the file repeated a bunch

Comment: In your code,token is defined a variable of type 'char *'. If it works if i write a[count] = (char**)token, change your code.

Comment: why would it repeat the final token over and over in the array?

Comment: You assign one pointer to string 'token' to all element of array a. So all element refferes same string which is updated last. This is why same data comes up again and again. (This is not a type-incompatible issue).

Answer (score 0):

If

> a[] is an array of strings

then

```
readTokens(char *fileName, char** a[])
```

is most certainly wrong and Fumu 7's guess *type of a[] may be 'char *'* is right, i. e. it has to be

```
readTokens(char *fileName, char *a[])
```

- cp. the call of the function `readTokens()`.